# What is the lexical equivalent of "syntax"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to find a word that means "lexical rules" (or perhaps not rules, but "tokens" I guess?); kind of like how *syntax* means "syntactic rules", but I'm unable to find one.

In other words: *syntactic* is to *syntax* as *lexical* is to what?

Comment: Syntactic -> syntax :: lexical -> lexicon

Comment: @Hellion: Ahhhhh thanks! Would you mind posting it as an answer please? :)

Comment: A **lexical rule** is in a form of syntactic rule used within many theories of natural language syntax. These rules alter the argument structures of lexical items (for example verbs and declensions) in order to alter their combinatory properties. [Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_rule]

Comment: "One possible reason to retain the constructor in the lexical component of a grammar could be to narrow the domain of application for a lexical rule." [Neal Whitman: books.google.com/books?isbn=0415970946]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Syntactic* is to *Syntax* as *lexical* is to ... ***lexicon***.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the word you are looking for is "grammar".

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicon for why "lexicon" is not the right words (it means the catalog of words, not the rules for how to use them).

Comment: I think "grammar" includes both lexical and syntactic rules, right? I think lexicon seems closer to what I needed, but +1 for the alternative.